# Защита текста от копирования

Tags: защита

В общем, я знаю что есть много способов защиты от выделения, подстановка в текста или удаление текста при копировании, однако это все не подходит, т.к. текст все еще остается на странице и обойти подобные защиты довольно просто. Сразу скажу, такая защита нужна для сайта с авторскими переводами различных произведений, т.е. нужно защитить довольно объемный кусок текста. Видел на некоторых сайтах преобразуют текст в изображение, но не понял как это реализовали, был бы благодарен если бы высказали свои предположения как это было сделано. В общем к сути, возможно ли вывести текст на сайт без возможности копирования, может через окно по типу флеш-игр, или же как вышеописанно через картинки. Я пока знаю лишь базовые основы погромирования сайтов, поэтому хотел бы узнать, в какую сторону копать и какой язык программирования подойдет для этой задачи, JavaScript, или еще какой?

Comment: Есть один надежный способ - просто не выкладывайте свои тексты в интернет

Comment: К сожалению, JavaScript нам не поможет, его можно просто отключить в браузере для определённого сайта :(

Comment: `Есть один надежный способ - просто не выкладывайте свои тексты в интернет` ну или знание 4 части ГК РФ и того, что авторское право возникает в момент создания произведение и не требует для своей работы регистрации или соблюдения иных формальностей (статья 1259 ГК РФ). Если автор хочет доказать, что это произведение его, то в тексте можно легко спрятать некоторые уникальные маркеры ну, а если это может привести к потере больших денег, то есть кардинальные методы, типа распечатки текста и отправки его себе письмом через Почту России, письмо не распечатывается, нужен просто штампель для суда

Answer (score 1):

если вы говорите про браузер, то ничего вы не сделаете, потому что из консоли разработчика весь этот сайт можно разобрать на кусочки, а также можно скопировать страницу на диск и разобрать ее на кусочки вне браузера и извлечь вообще всё, что нужно

если же вы хотите защитить авторские права, но это делать надо не на сайте :)

P.S.

если уж совсем приперло - воспользуйтесь этим кодом

```html
<body oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false">

<div onmousedown='return false;' onselectstart='return false;'>
Текст не копируется :)
До тех пор, пока кнопка F12 не будет нажата и не запущена консоль разработчика
</div>

</body>
```

закрыто выделение текста (но если постараться, то можно), копирование текста, даже через выпадающее меню и т.д.

Но мне больше Гражданский Кодекс нравится :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131216/discussion-on-answer-by-zhihar----).